# phpMyAdmin - #2002 A connection attempt failed

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have XAMPP installed in my local machine and I want to access a **remote** database.

I have changed the config.ini.php file and added the remote server info:

These are the lines I have added:

```
    $i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'hostname';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'username';   //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';       // keep it as config
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = FALSE;
```

When I go to the localhost/phpmyadmin/ page the localhost is there by default and working. But when I select the remote server I get the following error message:

> `#2002 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Should this work? Or do I have to install phpMyAdmin directly on the remote server? If so I just need to copy/paste the phpMyAdmin files?

Regards.

Comment: did you check if that "remote" server is actually set up to allow tcp connections?

Comment: I asked the server company but they did not answer. Is there anyway I can check? But am I doing everything right?

Comment: if you can't connect to the remote db via the command line mysql app, then phpmyadmin won't be able to either.

Comment: you are trying to get access to the PHPMYADMIN of server from the loca l system right?

Comment: There is a 99% chance that the traffic is either blocked by hardware/software firewall, traffic not even routed to the server from public IP or MySQL not configured to allow remote connections (from public IP). If you can setup phpMyAdmin on the database server directly, that should work then.

Comment: right. from my local machine. I have changed the config.ini.php file. But I don't know if it is enough.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks. When you say "setup phpMyAdmin on the database server directly" you mean copy/paste the phpmyAdmin files and then go to www.myurl.com/phpmyadmin . Is that it?

Comment: When I said `on the database server directly` I ment on a server inside the database network that is allowed to access the database, sorry, it's a bit more complicated. You cannot simply put files on a server and expect it to work right away. You need to setup a webserver which also needs to be routed/forwarded/opened. We need more information about your network to tell what to do. You better ask your network administrator here.

Comment: Thank you @DanFromGermany. I have started as a Database Administrator and I am a bit confused. I believe the company that hosts the server should grant me and prepare the access to the phpMyAdmin. Am I right? I am a bit lost here...

Comment: @frankmookie First you need to know if there is a hardware firewall (Cisco ASA for example), then you need to know wether there is a software firewall on the db server(s) (iptables for example), if there are no restrictions, you need to check the config on the server(s) `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` for `bind-address` (Google this configuration to get explanation). Last thing to make sure is to check database `mysql` table `users` if there are `host` restrictions.